# is it possible to set the Indeterminate Progress (spinning wheel ) to an Image View?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, animationdrawable

I am using a FAB and I would like to set the image to the Indeterminate Progress (Spinning Wheel) , I am thinking if maybe there is an AnimationDrawable that can be set?

Comment: Are you familiar with the xml property `android:indeterminate` of `ProgressBar`?

Comment: I am asking actually how to set it on a FAB as it extends ImageView.